# Inversion mapping complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the inversion mapping $w = f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ maps: the
>   circle $|z-1|=1$ onto the vertical line $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

From what I know thus far, I can see that $|z-1|=1$ take $\theta$ from $2\pi > \theta > 0$ will traverse the circle at $z= 1 + e^{i\theta}$, am I right on that since the graph of the function is shifted to the right with radius one, thus $z= 1 + e^{i\theta}$? I do not know how to finish the proof.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a function $w=f(z)$ where $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$.

The trick to this types of question is to compute the inverse. If $w = \frac{1}{z}$ then $z=\frac{1}{w}$. It follows:

$$z-1 = \frac{1}{w}-1 = \frac{1-w}{w} \, . $$

Taking the modulus of both sides gives:

$$|z-1|=\left| \frac{1-w}{w}\right| =\frac{|1-w|}{|w|} \, . $$

We know that $|z-1|=1$ and so, by multiplying both sides by $|w|$, we get $|w|=|1-w|$, or equivalently, $|w|=|w-1|$. By definition, this is the set of points $w$ equi-distant from $w=0$ and $w=1$, i.e. the perpendicular bisector: the line $\Re (w) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Very nice crisp answer! But I am stuck on the very last sentence on how you got the perpendicular bisector to be the line $\Re (w) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: **Geometrically**: The set of points equi-distant from two points is the perpendicular bisector.

**Algebraically**: We need $|w|=|w-1|$. Let $w=x+iy$ and consider $|x+iy|=|(x-1)+iy|$. We get, after squaring both sides, $x^2+y^2=(x-1)^2+y^2$ and in turn $x^2=(x-1)^2$. Expanding gives $x^2=x^2-2x+1$ and so $1-2x=0$ or $x=1/2.$

Comment: @Q.matin You're more than welcome. Notice that this method works for any Möbius transformation, i.e.

$$w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \, , $$

where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers and $c$ and $d$ are not both zero. Just invert to get $z=\ldots$ and work from there.

Answer (score 12):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282299), this fact can be proven geometrically.

Alternatively, we can parametrize the circle by
$$
z(t)=1+e^{it}
$$
Then, inverting maps this to
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z(t)}
&=\frac1{1+e^{it}}\\
&=\frac1{1+\cos(t)+i\sin(t)}\frac{1+\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}{1+\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1+\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}{(1+\cos(t))^2+\sin^2(t)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1+\cos(t)-i\sin(t)}{2+2\cos(t)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac12-\frac i2\tan\left(\frac t2\right)
\end{align}
$$
which parametrizes the line $\mathrm{Re}(z)=\frac12$.

Comment: One question, how did you know to parameterize the circle by $z(t)=1+e^{it}$?

Comment: Because $|z-1|=|(1+e^{it})-1|=|e^{it}|=1$

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old post, but if you can't immediately see that $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ is the parametrisation of the line $Re(z)=\frac{1}{2}$, is there a way to work this out?

Comment: @Bell: the fact that $\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac12-\frac{\color{#C00}i}2\tan\left(\frac t2\right)\right)=\frac12$ seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes of course, I misread the answer. Thanks

Comment: What about $z=\rho(1+e^{it})$?

Comment: @Sigur: what about it? $|z-\rho|=\rho$ is mapped to the line $z=\frac1{2\rho}+\frac{i}{2\rho}\tan\left(\frac t2\right)$.